# Get friends info from Facebook on my iPhone app

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

I am developing an application for iPhone that uses facebook.
I need to get my data (the data of current user).

I'm sure I made the correct login and have obtained the proper permissions.

Now,

I want a NSArray with the data and make a print with NSLog oh this data.

I have made this for the friendlist and i have no problem:

```
-(IBAction)friendsInfo:(id)sender{

   //  get the logged-in user's friends
   [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/friends" andDelegate:self];

  }

- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result {
    //ok so it's a dictionary with one element (key="data"), which is an array of dictionaries, each with "name" and "id" keys
    items = [(NSDictionary *)result objectForKey:@"data"];
    for (int i=0; i<[items count]; i++) {
        NSDictionary *friend = [items objectAtIndex:i];
        long long fbid = [[friend objectForKey:@"id"]longLongValue];
        NSString *name = [friend objectForKey:@"name"];
        NSLog(@"id: %lld - Name: %@", fbid, name);
    }
}
```

But for my info the same method not work:

```
-(IBAction)myInfo:(id)sender{

    // get information about the currently logged in user
    [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me" andDelegate:self];

     }
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this function to get your faceBook Info (logged in user info)

```
- (void)fetchUserDetails {
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               @"SELECT uid, name, pic FROM user WHERE uid=me()", @"query",nil];

[fb requestWithMethodName:@"fql.query"
                                 andParams:params
                             andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                               andDelegate:self];
```

}

Comment: THANK YOU for this good solution. The problem of my code was the data returned. I have understood the solution with this method:           - (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result {
    //Get a description of Result
    
    NSLog(@"\nDESCRIPTION: %@", [result description]); }

Answer (score 1):

```
          -(void)addList:(FBSession *)session {
    NSString* fql = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                     @"select uid from user where uid == %lld",    session.uid];

    NSDictionary* params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:fql forKey:@"query"];
    sessionView = session;
    [[FBRequest requestWithDelegate:self] call:@"facebook.friends.get" params:params];


}

         - (void)request:(FBRequest*)request didLoad:(id)result {
    if(myList==nil) {
        NSArray* users = result;
        myList =[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray: users];
        for(NSInteger i=0;i<[users count];i++) {
            NSDictionary* user = [users objectAtIndex:i];
            NSString* uid = [user objectForKey:@"uid"];
            NSString* fql = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                         @"select name from user where uid == %@", uid];

            NSDictionary* params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:fql          forKey:@"query"];
            [[FBRequest requestWithDelegate:self] call:@"facebook.fql.query"     params:params];
        }
    }
    else {
        NSArray* users = result;
        NSDictionary* user = [users objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString* name = [user objectForKey:@"name"];
        txtView.text=[NSString     localizedStringWithFormat:@"%@%@,\n",txtView.text,name];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(IBAction)getMeFriendsButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    FbGraphResponse *fb_graph_response = [fbGraph doGraphGet:@"me/friends" withGetVars:nil];
    NSLog(@"getMeFriendsButtonPressed:  %@", fb_graph_response.htmlResponse);

    NSDictionary *DictTmp = [fb_graph_response.htmlResponse JSONValue];
    NSMutableArray *myFriendList=[[DictTmp objectForKey:@"data"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString* fql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select uid,name from user where uid == %lld", session.uid];

NSDictionary* params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:fql forKey:@"query"];
[[FBRequest requestWithDelegate:self] call:@"facebook.fql.query" params:params];
[[FBRequest requestWithDelegate:self] call:@"facebook.friends.get" params:params];
```